# Highchart printing issues in IE 7

Tags: highcharts, internet-explorer-7

None of my charts are printing in IE7 and also IE9 in document mode 7 or 8.
The text(axis titles, axis labels, legend labels) comes up but the chart itself and the legend symbols do not.

I did try to search a lot and saw a few posts suggesting issues with document modes but the chart not printing in a simple IE7 browser seems strange. I do need to support printing for my sites users!
Any pointers would be great.

Comment: 1. Check if you have the latest version of Highcharts
2. See if this happens no more than one computer/printer
3. Share the code that's giving you this problem

Comment: 1) Yes I am using the latest version of HighCharts. 2) This is happening in quite a few computers. 3) I cannot share the code but 1 observation I made is that the demos in the highcharts url also do not show up in my IE7 browser. Does that help.

Comment: Do you receive any errors?